# why do I have to enter the sentinel value twice to exit the loop?

Tags: c++, data-structures

I am pretty new to c++ . I am learning about link list right now . My program should terminate when I enter 0 but I have to enter the sentinel value ( which is 0 ) twice and how can I not insert the 0 into the list ?  Can someone please explain to me what's happening and thanks for your time , I really appreciate it .

[this is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HkiKr.png)

This is my code .

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
template <class T>
class List {
private:
    struct Node {
    T data;         
    Node *link; };
    Node *pHead, *pCurr;
    int numItem;

public:
    List();   ~List();
    int AddToFront();
    bool Traverse(T, int &);
    void PrintData();
    int NumberOfItem();
    int Item(int );
};

using namespace std;

template <class T>
List<T>::List() {
    numItem = 0; pHead = NULL;
}

template <class T> List<T>::~List() {}

template <class T> int List<T>::AddToFront() {
    T item  ; Node *pNew = new Node;
        cout << "\nEnter Registration No : ";
        cin >> item;
        pNew->data = item;
        pNew->link = pHead;
        pHead = pNew;
        numItem++;
        return item;
}



template <class T> bool List<T>::Traverse(T target, int &loc) {
    if (numItem == 0)  cout << "List is empty\n";
    else {
        pCurr = pHead;  loc = 0;
        while (pCurr->data != target &&   pCurr->link != NULL) {
            pCurr = pCurr->link;
            loc++;
        }
        if (pCurr->data == target)   return true;
        else   return false;
    }
}

template <class T>
void List<T>::PrintData() {
    pCurr = pHead;
    while (pCurr != NULL) {

            cout << pCurr->data << " ";
            pCurr = pCurr->link;
        }

cout << endl;
}

template <class T> int List<T>::NumberOfItem() { return numItem; }
template <class T> int List<T>::Item(int item) { return item; }

template class List<int>;


int main() {
    int target, location;
    List<int> x;
    cout << "\nBasement Parking\n ";


    while (x.AddToFront() != 0); {
        x.AddToFront();
    } 



        cout << "\nNumber of car(s) parked : " << x.NumberOfItem() - 1;
        cout << "\nThe list are : " << endl;
        x.PrintData();
        cout << "\nEnter the search item : "; cin >> target;

        if (x.Traverse(target, location) == true)     cout << "Car found at location : " << "location " << location + 1 << endl;
        else     cout << "Item not found\n\n";

}
```

Comment: Suggestion: Run your program step by step through a debugger. Watch what happens.

Comment: Trim it down. The question has nothing to do with the List class. Post a [MCVE].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you call AddToFront twice in the while loop.
The first call you check the return value to see if you should stop looping, the second call you don't use the value.

Here's a small example of what you are currently doing

```
#include <iostream>

int test() {
    int x;
    std::cin >> x;
    return x;
}

int main() {
    while (test() != 0) {
        test();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Since you aren't using the return value of AddToFront except to check when to stop adding values you could instead change it to something like this

```
#include <iostream>

int test() {
    int x;
    std::cin >> x;
    return x;
}

int main() {
    while (test() != 0);

    return 0;
}
```

This is a while loop with no body and will call the test function until the return value is zero.
To prevent zero from being inserted into the list you could wrap the lines that insert a value in a if statement

```
template <class T> int List<T>::AddToFront() {
T item  ; Node *pNew = new Node;
    cout << "\nEnter Registration No : ";
    cin >> item;
    if (item != 0) {
        pNew->data = item;
        pNew->link = pHead;
        pHead = pNew;
        numItem++;
    }
    return item;
}
```